# Cors and web resource

Tags: web, resources, cors

Im trying to figure what is cors.
In MDN it describe as :

> A resource makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain than the one which the first resource itself serves.

Im not sure I know what is a web resource.
In addition, I understand thats cors allows me to use web resource from another domain in my domain by putting the domain in the header, but is it just convention or something more than that?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to give a short explanation.

**Web resource**

A web resource is anything you request on the web. That could be an image, a json payload, a pdf, an html-page etc. There's not more to it than that.

**CORS**

When you want to do an ajax-request in a browser (typically from javascript), you are typically limited to making requests to resources (url's) on the same domain. Eg. `www.x.com` can only request resources from `www.x.com`. Let's imagine you have a web page on `www.x.com` that want's to get a resource from `api.x.com`. This will not be possible unless the server (`api.x.com`) has CORS enabled.

So how does it work? Well, the flow is like this (simplified a lot).

When you do a ajax-request, for instance a GET request for a json payload, the browser sees this and issues an OPTIONS request to server in which it states who it is (`www.x.com` in the `Origin` header). The server is then supposed to answer with a response with a header saying that it is ok for `www.x.com` to do the GET request. The server does this by adding a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.x.com`. If the allowed origin matches the origin in the request, the browser issues the GET request and the json payload is returned by the server. If the allowed origin does not match, the browser refuses to do the request and shows an error in the console.

If you are doing the client (`www.x.com`), and are using - lets say jquery - you don't have to do anything. Everything happens automatically.

If you are doing the server (`api.x.com`), you have to enabled CORS. How this is done varies a lot but http://enable-cors.org/server.html has a nice guide on how to do it on different server types. They also have some more in depth guides on how it works. Specifically you might wanna take a look here https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

I hope this helps you out a bit

Comment: Hey @paz-reingold. Did my answer help you out. If so please mark my answer as "accepted answer" by clicking the checkmark next the answer. If not - please let me know why not.