# include html file from another website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried this but it does not work form other website

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>    
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("https://mywebsite.com/file.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

and

```
    <div id="includedContent"></div>
```

Comment: Cross origin policy. Please check out your developer console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cors and web resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348682/cors-and-web-resource)

Answer (score 1):

you must use `iframe` tag to load the html page.
`iframe` is the tag which you can use for call other html pages into your web page

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.co.in" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<iframe src="https://www.my website.com/file.html"></iframe>
```

If this doesn't work, just comment on this answer.